# RoR model relationship suggestion needed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, foreign-key-relationship, relationship

I have 3 models category, question and quiz and 5 tables categories, questions, quizzes, category_quizzes, and questions_quizzes.

A quiz has many questions and may belongs to zero or more categories. Also a question may belongs to many quizzes

Can some body suggest how should be the relationship between the models

table schema follows

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
  id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  title varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (id),
);

CREATE TABLE category_quizzes (
  id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  category_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  quiz_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (id),
  KEY category_id (category_id,quiz_id),
  KEY quiz_id (quiz_id)
);

CREATE TABLE questions (
  id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  question varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  answer varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (id),
);

CREATE TABLE questions_quizzes (
  id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  quiz_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  question_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (id),
  KEY quiz_id (quiz_id,question_id),
  KEY question_id (question_id)
);

CREATE TABLE quizzes (
  id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  title varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (id),
);
```

My current model classes

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :quiz
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :quiz
end

class Quiz < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many   :questions
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The migration for the table category_quizzes is not correct. It should be categories_quizzes, both in plural form.

Then you could specify the associations like this:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :quizzes
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :quizzes
end

class Quiz < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :questions
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end
```

Edit: Changed the associations according to your comment